# Could not create query for public Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two classes Employee and Asset. they have a relationship @ManyToOne.
When I try to left join tables console shows a runtime error.
Please

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'assetController' defined in file [C:\Users\User\Desktop\material-assets\target\classes\com\alsecotask\materialassets\controller\AssetController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'assetService' defined in file [C:\Users\User\Desktop\material-assets\target\classes\com\alsecotask\materialassets\service\AssetService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'assetRepository' defined in com.alsecotask.materialassets.repository.AssetRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.alsecotask.materialassets.repository.AssetRepository.getAssetsByEmployee()! Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.alsecotask.materialassets.repository.AssetRepository.getAssetsByEmployee()!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.alsecotask.materialassets.repository.AssetRepository.getAssetsByEmployee()!
```

AssetReposiory where I wrote my query

```
public interface AssetRepository extends JpaRepository<Asset, Long> {

Long countAssetByEmployee_Id(Long id);

@Query("SELECT Employee.id, Employee.firstName, sum(Asset .price), count(Asset .price)\n" +
        "FROM Asset \n" +
        "         LEFT JOIN Employee \n" +
        "                   ON Employee .id = Asset .employee.id group by Employee .id\n")
List<?> getAssetsByEmployee();

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Asset WHERE name = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
Asset findByNameQuery(String name);
```

}

Asset class

```
public class Asset {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String name;
private double price;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
private Employee employee;}
```

Employee class

```
public class Employee {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "employee_sequence",
        sequenceName = "employee_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1
)
@GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "employee_sequence"
)
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
public Employee(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

}

]

Comment: Do not post code as screenshots, but as text formatted as code. Always include the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type as `List<Object[]>`.

```
@Query(value="SELECT Employee.id, Employee.firstName, sum(Asset 
.price), count(Asset .price)\n" +
    "FROM Asset \n" +
    "         LEFT JOIN Employee \n" +
    "                   ON Employee .id = Asset .employee.id group by 
Employee.id\n", nativeQuery= true)
List<Object[]> getAssetsByEmployee();
```